# c programming query regarding sizeof operator Please specifythe output with reason in windows and linux

Tags: c, sizeof

```
void main()
{
    char c='0';
    printf("%d %d",sizeof(c),sizeof('0'));
}
```

Comment: What output did you see when you ran it?

Comment: Do your own compiling, and ask a more specific question. Perhaps also check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof

Comment: The answer is 42. Write that down and hope the TA has a sense of humor.

Comment: Come on people.  You're not being very nice.  Clearly he's in the middle of his midterm now as we speak!  How can he be expected to compile!?

Answer (score 2):

In C, size of `char literal` is equal to `sizeof(int)`. So `sizeof('0')` gives the value of `sizeof(int)` on your implementation.

Also `sizeof(char)` is always 1 as mandated by the Standard.

Answer (score 0):

The output will be `1 4`. The type of the `'0'` literal is `int`, which on most systems has a size of `4`. The C standard requires that `sizeof(char)` is `1`.

If you get anything less than `4`, get in your time machine, and dial in `+25 years`.

Comment: butturbo c gives  output as 1,1

Comment: @user : Did you compile the program as `*.cpp` on Turbo?

Comment: I believe Turbo C predates the Standard.

Comment: The output _may_ be 4, it may also be 2, or 7000. As long as the `int` can take the range -32767 thru 32767 inclusive, the standard allows any value (with the usual provisos, including that is has to be at least as big as a `short` and no bigger than a `long`, blah blah blah). I just find it annoying when someone only half-quotes the standards :-)